# Displaying images, and next to every image display if it has been favorited by the user

Tags: python, sql, django

This is roughly my model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
  url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Favorite(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="favorites")
  image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name="favorited")
```

I'm displaying a bunch of images and users can add images to their favorites. I want to display a star next to each image if the current user has it in his favorites. I can do it by using `raw` and then issuing a left join in the SQL, but I'd much rather do it without doing raw SQL. Is there any way to do it maybe using `extra`?

Comment: Please post the queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any extra sql, you can just query the related table to see if anything exists like this:\

```
images = Image.objects.all().prefetch_related('favorited')
for image in images:
    image.favorited = image.favorited.filter(user=current_user).exists()
```

Then you can check image.favorited in the template.

I think a little cleaner way would be to use `.extra()` with a little sql. Something like this:

```
image.objects.extra(select={'favorited': 'EXISTS(SELECT * FROM app_favorite WHERE image_id = app_image.id AND user_id = %s)'}, select_params=[current_user.pk])
```

Comment: Nice, just what I was looking for! Thanks a lot